# Handle Events with controls within Custom Components Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, event-handling, custom-controls

I have a custom component which basically needs to validate a number of controls on a form. The idea is that the programmer, at design time, can select a list of controls they would like to validate. At run-time, I would like to handle the Change event of each of the selected controls, and kick off the validation process.

I have created my component. It has a List property which stores the list of controls the programmer selected at design time (I implemented my own ListEditor to get this working). Now, at run time, I would like to wire up the Changed events of the controls in the list to the Validate method... And this is where I get stuck. when debugging the component at runtime, it never goes into the constructors. If I add the event handlers at design time, they don't fire at run-time.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Could you post a bit of code of how are you registering the events?

Comment: basically, AddHandler theControl.TextChanged, AddressOf ValidateMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully my answer is a little more descriptive than the original question.

Basically my problem is pretty simple. I have a custom component who's main duty is to do some validation on a group of controls on the form the component resides. At design time, the user selects these components from a list. The selected controls are stored / serialized in a property of the component (a generic List). At runtime, when one of the controls in the list are changed (i.e. TextChanged is fired), the validation routine needs to run on all the selected controls.

My problem was that I needed to add an event handler to each of the selected controls at run time. The setter for the property which stores the list is only called at design time (after the user selects the controls they want to validate), which means that adding the handler at this point is not going to work.

The solution? Instead of using a generic List I used a BindingList (can't use ObservableCollection... .net 2.0), and handled it's ListChanged event. When a new control is added to the List at run-time, I wire up the event for that control. The event is then fired, and everything works as it should.